# NativeContentAdView not clickable in UICollectionViewCell (Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, admob, uicollectionviewcell

Our ads should appear in UICollectionView as a cell amongst regular cells.

[image: Example]

I use storyboard to create the UI.

[image: Structure]

The UIView of the UICollectionView was configured to be GADNativeContentAdView.

I add the following code in the ad cell:

`self.nativeContentAdView.nativeContentAd = nativeAd`

But the ad do not respond to clicks. What is missing?

Additional info:
If I add `NativeContentAdView.xib` from [AdMob Example code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples) and load it inside my cell like this, the click works:

```
// Create and place the ad in the view hierarchy.
let contentAdView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("NativeContentAdView", owner: nil,
                                                           options: nil).first as! GADNativeContentAdView
setAdView(contentAdView)

// Associate the content ad view with the content ad object. This is required to make the ad
// clickable.
contentAdView.nativeContentAd = nativeAd
```

But I don't want to use .xib

Comment: Have you linked the outlets to your asset views as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/native-advanced#the_ad_view_classes? Consider posting more of your code.

Comment: @RedBrogdon, everything is connected. AndI've added some more details

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Anybody found a solution? Having the same issue..